# openssl_encrypt() error while running phpunit over Zend controllers

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I´m not sure if this is a PHP, Zend or a PHPUnit problem...

I have PHPunit 3.5.15 working fine with Zend Framework 1.11.11. When I try to dispatch to a specific controller which has a method using openssl_encrypt function, I got the following error, after call phpunit in command line:

```
C:\wamp\www\MyProject\tests>phpunit
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function openssl_encrypt() in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\application\utils\Crypt.php on line 16
```

All the extensions and modules are enabled in Apache and PHP, and the functions are working normally when I call the controller on the browser.

Does anyone have any idea about what is the problem?

Comment: phpunit will use the CLI version of PHP rather than the one Apache uses. Perhaps you somehow have different modules enabled there?

Comment: You are right, Tim! Wamp shows php_openssl enabled, but in php.ini, it wasn´t. I just changed it and now it is working fine. Thanks!